# Good examples in open source iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, open-source

I'm looking for good examples of open source iPhone applications.
Not tutorials, but complete applications that made it to the appStore.
So far the best I've seen is

http://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-iphone - a LastFM client, a very well designed app, and I am curious if there are others like it.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200850/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-applications-around

Comment: you are right, should've looked some more :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was messing around with iPhone/iPod Touch apps I found; 
http://maniacdev.com/2009/06/11-open-source-iphone-app-store-apps-to-learn-from/

It helped me a lot, hopefully it can help you :)
Lawrence

Answer (score 3):

[iOctocat](http://github.com/dbloete/ioctocat) is a pretty good app for viewing your github repos and stuff.

Comment: I've pulled down tons of iPhone OSS projects and this is one of the very few that actually compiles right out of the box.  The author is now my hero.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [AppsAmuck](http://www.appsamuck.com/).

Most of these are pretty simple, but some of them are (or at least were) in the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the Facebook application is going to be open-source, including [Connect](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/) which is. The author is working on an open source library that has much of the FB app's functionality but decoupled from the Facebook data model. [Looks](http://github.com/facebook/three20/) pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/ hosts all the code for the incredible Now Playing application.

Answer (score 0):

Task Coach for iPhone is open-source. Check the source [from Subversion](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taskcoach/develop).